# Как создать рабочий стол в Windows 10, но

Tags: администрирование

Как создать рабочий стол в Windows 10, но чтобы в него можно было зайти ТОЛЬКО запустив специальный ярлык ( и чтоб его не было видно ни обычным пользователям, ни админу )?

Comment: Админ по определению может видеть всё

Comment: окей тогда просто чтобы обычным пользователям не было видно